# Express js - how access a function not in same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `UserController` and database config file `db.js` and I want to some function in `UserController` access to a function in `db.js`.

In `UserController` I require `var db = require('../config/db');` and in function I do this `db.getDB('text');` but returns me an

> error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDB' of undefined`

#### UserController.js

```
 var db = require('../config/db');

module.exports =
{
  index: (req, res) => {
    console.log("User Index");
    res.send('user index');
  },
  getUser: (req, res) => {
    console.log("User by id " + req.params.userId);
    var dbname = "text";
    var db = db.getDB(dbname);
    res.send(db);
  }
}
```

#### db.js

```
module.exports =
{
  getDB: (req, res) => {
    console.log('db file');
    return req.params.dbname;
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it because you are declaring db again.

`var db = db.getDB(dbname);`

so `db` is not what you import anymore?

try:

`var myDb = db.getDb(dbname);`

Comment: Ok. In this way it goes to config/db but req.params.dbname is undefined.
If I console log in db.js the req.params returns me undefined too. @Tiago

Comment: Solved! I have to use just req and not req.params.dbname. Thank you @Tiago

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help @user3242861